# What is this electrical box with a button?

Tags: electrical

I have a small electrical box with a small button on it in the front of my house.  I traced the wire as much as I could.  One end is this box with a button.  It leads to the front of my detached garage.  Then the wire goes to the back of my garage (toward the back of the house), where it appears to go through drywall (I'm not sure where it goes from there).

Does anyone have any what this might be?  I considered pressing the button, but I have no idea what it is and was hoping someone might know!

Image attached...

Thanks in advance!
[image: Weird button on the front of the house next to garage, wire leads to back of garage]

Comment: Doorbell? How can you resist the temptation of a button.  PRESS IT.

Comment: It's small wires, so it should be low voltage. Probably 12 -24 volts.

Comment: Its unlikely to be a detonator :)

Comment: It opens the bat cave.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's how the city reads your water meter. You should be able to trace the wires back to your water meter, or if that isn't feasible, look at your water meter and you'll probably see a device on it with two wires of the same color.

I doubt that "button" can actually be pressed, rather it's the contact point where the meter reader places their probe to take the reading.

[image: Water Meter Reader]
<sub>(source: [thetimes-tribune.com](http://thetimes-tribune.com/polopoly_fs/1.1154919!/image/2655110395.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_490/2655110395.jpg))</sub>